# How to use nl2br to fetch data of textarea using php?

Tags: php, mysql, textarea, nl2br

I am new in php. I have a web form. In which i use textarea. I have another PHP page where I display data from db and applying CRUD operation. Now here is the problem when I click on Edit button my all form data has been fetched from db but the formatting of textarea Text has been changed. It shows `\r\r\r\n` I use `nl2br` but its not working. I want to display my data in same formating.

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="text" name="text" style="font-size:14px;" > <?php echo !empty(nl2br($text))?(nl2br($text)):'';?> </textarea><td>
```

My Full Page Code is

```
<?php
    require 'database.php';
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }

    if ( null==$id ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track post values
        $file_name = $_POST['file_name'];
$ref_no = $_POST['ref_no'];
$to_name = $_POST['to_name'];
$confidential = $_POST['confidential'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$solutation = $_POST['solutation'];
$entity = $_POST['entity'];
$add_1 = $_POST['add_1'];
$thank_you = $_POST['thank_you'];
$add_2 = $_POST['add_2'];
$yours_truly = $_POST['yours_truly'];
$add_3 = $_POST['add_3'];
$sign_name = $_POST['sign_name'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$s_designation = $_POST['s_designation'];
$heading_line_1 = $_POST['heading_line_1'];
$encl_line_1 = $_POST['encl_line_1'];
$heading_line_2 = $_POST['heading_line_2'];
$encl_line_2 = $_POST['encl_line_2'];
$heading_line_3 = $_POST['heading_line_3'];
$encl_line_3 = $_POST['encl_line_3'];
$text = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['text'] );


    // update data
    $valid = true;
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
          //  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE test  set file_name ='$file_name', ref_no ='$ref_no', to_name ='$to_name',
                                        confidential ='$confidential', designation = '$designation', date ='$date',
                                        solutation ='$solutation', entity ='$entity', add_1 ='$add_1',
                                        thank_you ='$thank_you', add_2 ='$add_2', yours_truly ='$yours_truly',
                                        add_3 ='$add_3', sign_name ='$sign_name', city ='$city',
                            s_designation ='$s_designation', heading_line_1 ='$heading_line_1', encl_line_1 ='$encl_line_1',
                            heading_line_2 ='$heading_line_2', encl_line_2 ='$encl_line_2', heading_line_3 ='$heading_line_3',
                            encl_line_3 ='$encl_line_3', text ='$text'  WHERE id ='$id'";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($file_name,$ref_no,$to_name,$confidential,$designation,$date,$solutation,$entity,$add_1,
            $thank_you,$add_2,$yours_truly,$add_3,$sign_name,$city,$s_designation,$heading_line_1,$encl_line_1,$heading_line_2,
            $encl_line_2,$heading_line_3,$encl_line_3,$id));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
     else {
          }
    }
         $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","MY_LOGIN","MY_PASSWORD","MY_DATABASE");

         $id2 = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test where id='$id2'";

            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $row= (mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC));


        $file_name = $row['file_name'];
$ref_no = $row['ref_no'];
$to_name = $row['to_name'];
$confidential = $row['confidential'];
$designation = $row['designation'];
$date = $row['date'];
$solutation = $row['solutation'];
$entity = $row['entity'];
$add_1 = $row['add_1'];
$thank_you = $row['thank_you'];
$add_2 = $row['add_2'];
$yours_truly = $row['yours_truly'];
$add_3 = $row['add_3'];
$sign_name = $row['sign_name'];
$city = $row['city'];
$s_designation = $row['s_designation'];
$heading_line_1 = $row['heading_line_1'];
$encl_line_1 = $row['encl_line_1'];
$heading_line_2 = $row['heading_line_2'];
$encl_line_2 = $row['encl_line_2'];
$heading_line_3 = $row['heading_line_3'];
$encl_line_3 = $row['encl_line_3'];
$text = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['text'] );

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newstyles.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function show_confirm(){
        return confirm("Copy is being created....");
        window.location.href='index.php';
    }
</script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }).datepicker();
});   

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form action="edit4.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="POST" > 
 <table border="0" class="DivTableBorder" width="840px">
      <tr>
        <td class="DivSubHeaderCellTop"  colspan="6">Letters</td>
</tr> <tr>  </td>  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">File Name </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="file_name" type="text" id="file_name" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($file_name)?$file_name:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
      <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Referance #</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px"><input name="ref_no" type="text" id="ref_no" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($ref_no)?$ref_no:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td> </tr>

<tr ><td bgcolor="#999999" colspan="4"></td>
 <td class="DivCellText" width="80px"></td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px"></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">To - Name</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="to_name" type="text" id="to_name" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($to_name)?$to_name:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
<td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Confidential</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
    <?php if($confidential == "on"){ ?>
    <input name="confidential" type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="confidential" value="on"  />
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <input name="confidential" type="checkbox" id="confidential" value="on"  />
    <?php } ?>

    </td> </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Designation</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="designation" type="text" id="designation" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($designation)?$designation:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Date :</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
            <input name="date" type="text" id="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
    </td> </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" >&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Solutation</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >

    <select name='solutation' id='solutation' size='1' STYLE='width: 95%' value="<?php echo !empty($solutation)?$solutation:'';?>" >
    <option value='Others' >[--Others--]</option>
    <option value='Dear Sir' >Dear Sir</option>
    <option value='Madam' >Madam</option>
    </select>
    </td> </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Entity</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="entity" type="text" id="entity" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($entity)?$entity:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >

    <input name="txtSolutation" type="text" id="txtSolutation" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td> </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add-1</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="add_1" type="text" id="add_1" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($add_1)?$add_1:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
         <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Thank You.</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" ><input name="thank_you" type="text" id="thank_you" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($thank_you)?$thank_you:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add-2</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="add_2" type="text" id="add_2" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($add_2)?$add_2:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
         <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Yours truly</td>
         <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >
    <select name='yours_truly' id='yours_truly' size='1' STYLE='width: 95%' value="<?php echo !empty($yours_truly)?$yours_truly:'';?>" >
    <option value='1' >Yours truly</option>
    <option value='2' >Regards</option>
    </select>

    </td> </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add-3</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="add_3" type="text" id="add_3" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($add_3)?$add_3:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Signature-Name</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >

    <select name='sign_name'  id='sign_name' size='1' style='width:95%' value="<?php echo !empty($sign_name)?$sign_name:'';?>"> 
        <option value='1' >Adnan Afaq</option>
        <option value='2' >Muhammad Shahzad Saleem</option>
        <option value='3' >Adnan Dilawar</option>
        <option value='4' >Rana Muhammad Nadeem</option>
        <option value='5' >Jhangeer Hanif</option>
    </select>
    </td> </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;City</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="city" type="text" id="city" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($city)?$city:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">S-Designation</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
    <select name='s_designation' id='s_designation' size='1' STYLE='width: 95%' value="<?php echo !empty($s_designation)?$s_designation:'';?>" >
    <option value='1' >Managing Director</option>
    <option value='2' >Chief Operating Officer</option>
    <option value='3' >Manager Ratings</option>
    <option value='4' >Unit Head Ratings</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Heading Line-1</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="heading_line_1" type="text" id="heading_line_1" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($heading_line_1)?$heading_line_1:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  maxlength="55"/>
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Encl: Line-1</td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >
     <input name="encl_line_1" type="text" id="encl_line_1" value="<?php echo !empty($encl_line_1)?$encl_line_1:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Heading Line-2</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="heading_line_2" type="text" id="heading_line_2" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($heading_line_2)?$heading_line_2:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"    maxlength="55" />
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Line-2</td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >
     <input name="encl_line_2" type="text" id="encl_line_2" value="<?php echo !empty($encl_line_2)?$encl_line_2:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
  </tr>  
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Heading Line-3</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="heading_line_3" type="text" id="heading_line_3" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($heading_line_3)?$heading_line_3:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"    maxlength="55" />
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Line-3</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
         <input name="encl_line_3" type="text" id="encl_line_3" value="<?php echo !empty($encl_line_3)?$encl_line_3:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr ><td bgcolor="#999999" colspan="6"></td></tr>
<tr ><td colspan="6">
 <table  border="0" class="DivTableBorder" width="840px">
 <tr>
<td class="DivCellText" colspan="4">
<textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="text" name="text" style="font-size:14px;" > <?php echo !empty(nl2br($text))?(nl2br($text)):'';?> </textarea><td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Copy" onclick="return show_confirm();" class="blueButton"></input></td>
<td width="100"><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel" class="blueButton"  /> </td>
<td width="100">

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="blueButton"></input>
   </td>
<td width="303">  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="blueButton"> </input> </td>
<td width="209">
                          <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a> </td>
</tr>

</table>




</form>

<?php

$_POST['submit']="";

if($_POST['submit'] == "Create Copy"){
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("pacra1", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$file_name = $_POST['file_name'];
$ref_no = $_POST['ref_no'];
$to_name = $_POST['to_name'];
$confidential = $_POST['confidential'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];

$date = $_POST['date'];
$solutation = $_POST['solutation'];
$entity = $_POST['entity'];
$add_1 = $_POST['add_1'];
$thank_you = $_POST['thank_you'];
$add_2 = $_POST['add_2'];
$yours_truly = $_POST['yours_truly'];
$add_3 = $_POST['add_3'];
$sign_name = $_POST['sign_name'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$s_designation = $_POST['s_designation'];
$heading_line_1 = $_POST['heading_line_1'];
$encl_line_1 = $_POST['encl_line_1'];
$heading_line_2 = $_POST['heading_line_2'];
$encl_line_2 = $_POST['encl_line_2'];
$heading_line_3 = $_POST['heading_line_3'];
$encl_line_3 = $_POST['encl_line_3'];
$text = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['text'] );
//$txtTitle = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['txtTitle'] );
//$txtRational = $_POST['txtRational'];


//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(file_name, ref_no, to_name, confidential, designation, date, solutation, entity, add_1, thank_you, add_2, yours_truly, add_3, sign_name, city, s_designation, heading_line_1, encl_line_1, heading_line_2, encl_line_2, heading_line_3, encl_line_3, text) 

                                        values 

    ('$file_name', '$ref_no', '$to_name', '$confidential', '$designation', '$date', '$solutation', '$entity', '$add_1', '$thank_you', '$add_2', '$yours_truly', '$add_3', '$sign_name', '$city', '$s_designation', '$heading_line_1', '$encl_line_1', '$heading_line_2', '$encl_line_2', '$heading_line_3', '$encl_line_3', '$text')");
echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
}
else{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
}

//mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the insert into database code?

Comment: How are you creating the `$text` variable? I'd recommend using the nl2br **before** entering the text to the database - that way you can echo it to a page naturally. Then to return the data to a textarea, use `str_replace` to exchange the line break tags with new line characters.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins please can u give a demo syntax for it? I am new born in php.

Comment: `nl2br()` function replace `[\n\r]+` not `[/n/r]+`, You have something wrong with your insertion in database....

Comment: @GeoffAtkins > I don't think that's a good approach. Ideally content in the database should be independant of presentation layer : if OP ever want to use this text in a report, in a excel sheet or anywhere with no HTML support, he better keep strings with no HTML in it.

Comment: @Bartdude - that is a fair comment and a good point, I was looking at just the details of the problem with the information at hand. I deleted my answer which expanded on my original comment.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I am waiting your answer

Comment: @GeoffAtkins > Your answer might help the OP on how to use the function. Just because the approach is (to my opinion) not the best one doesn't mean the answer is wrong. Never hesitate to post an answer if you think it might be valuable, downvotes will clearly indicate how good the community thinks it is. For example I would probably have commented your answer the same way, but certainly not downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your php echo code as you dont need to include the !empty verification. If you do then you will have to create that before you echo the textbox. I suggest you change your code to this:

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="text" name="text" style="font-size:14px;" > <?php echo nl2br($text);?> </textarea><td>
```

You can also find some documentation of the nl2br here :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Could you post your full page code? Also use the nl2br when you inputing  the information to the database

Comment: I post my Full Page Code

Comment: @sunny at line 335 where you have $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text'] ); replace it with this $text = mysql_real_escape_string( nl2br($_POST['text']) ); then just echo it out and you should have all sorted

Answer (score 0):

Upon inserting to the database, apply the nl2br - as you are likely to be presenting that data as text on a page more often than an textarea.

`$mysql->real_escape_string(trim(nl2br($_POST['text'])))`

*Where `$mysql` is the mysqli database connection*

**Disclaimer** As Bartdude mentioned, this is not especially good practice, since the information in the database should be as free from tags as possible - however, if this data is to be used in HTML pages only, then this solution should work.

Then when returning the data to a textarea, simply remove the `<br>` tags, the newline characters will be there anyway and should be interpreted by the browser correctly.

`str_replace("<br>", " ", $row['text'])`

Comment: Would it make more sense to use the nl2br() at the time of display of the text, rather than at the time of storing it? When you use at the time of storing, it stores unnecessary amount of characters (<br /> or <br> for each new line).

Comment: @Envayo Yes, possibly, I did clarify that it wasn't especially good practice. I was aiming to answer without the OP having to re-write most of their code.